# Network Dialog does not show all nodes on network: Why?

Tags: windows, networking

There is a network dialog box thats sprinkled througout the Windows (XP,Vista, 7) OS that lets you browse the available nodes that are on your network.  For example, this dialog box appears when you try to map a network drive or printer and try to browse a network location.  This dialog box would be useful if several of the available nodes were not missing from the tree.  If I type the exact path of the share on the network, for example `\\server01\c`, it promptly asks for a username and password.  Yet, the node server01 does not appear on the list.  I've seen this issue before even back in the Windows 98/ME days where you used workgroups.  But in this instance, **all the nodes on the network are on a domain with an active directory/dns server visible to all nodes**.

My questions:  **What controls what is shown in this dialog box?**  Is there a setting on each node that needs to be enabled? a service?  Sometimes I can't always remember exact name/path of a share on the network and would be handy to be able to browse the network.

Things to note:

- The nodeset is mixed with XP Pro, 7 Pro, Server 2003, and Server 2008 Windows OS
- The network is has 5 different segments.

[image: Browse For Folder]